# JSON encoding complex arrays with json_encode in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, elasticsearch

I am trying to build up a Elasticsearch query in PHP using arrays and then using the `json_encode()` function to convert it to JSON, however, there seems to be something Elasticsearch is disliking:

Example of my array in PHP (relevant parts):

```
'query' => [
    'bool' => [
        'must' => [
            'multi_match' => [
                'query' => $request->get('keyword'),
                'fields' => ['addressLine1', 'addressCity', 'contactName']
            ],
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    'range' => [
                        '_metrics.count' => [
                            'gte' => 1
                        ]
                    ]
                 ]
            ]
        ],
        'filter' => [
            'term' => [
                'organisationId.keyword' => [
                    'value' => $organisationId
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

I am then JSON encoding this array (`json_encode($params)`) which results in the following JSON:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "multi_match":{
               "query":"277 Some Road",
               "fields":[
                  "addressLine1",
                  "addressCity",
                  "contactName"
               ]
            },
            "bool":{
               "should":{
                  "range":{
                     "_metrics.count":{
                        "gte":1
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "term":{
               "organisationId.keyword":{
                  "value":"xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have run the above through a couple of validators and it appears to be valid JSON, however, when sending this through to Elasticsearch, I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[multi_match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 16,
        "col": 13
      }
    ],
    "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
    "reason": "[16:13] [bool] failed to parse field [must]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "parsing_exception",
      "reason": "[multi_match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
      "line": 16,
      "col": 13
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I can modify the JSON query to:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "277 Some Road",
                "fields":[
                  "addressLine1",
                  "addressCity",
                  "contactName"
               ]
              }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "should":[
                     {
                        "range":{
                           "_metrics.count":{
                              "gte":1
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "organisationId.keyword":{
                     "value":"xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
                  }
               }
            }
          ]
      }
   }
}
```

which works, I get the expected result. The only difference I spotted was that the `must` is an array of objects, but no matter how I attempt to format the array in PHP `json_encode()` never seems to give me the correct result.

How can I match the JSON structure using an array and `json_encode()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `json_decode(yourjson, true)` with the working json, you'll see that you need to add another level inside of the `must`, so that it's an array of objects:

```
[
    "query" => [
      "bool" => [
        "must" => [
          [
            "multi_match" => [
              "query" => "277 Some Road",
              "fields" => [
                "addressLine1",
                "addressCity",
                "contactName",
              ],
            ],
          ],
          [
            "bool" => [
              "should" => [
                [
                  "range" => [
                    "_metrics.count" => [
                      "gte" => 1,
                    ],
                  ],
                ],
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
        "filter" => [
          [
            "term" => [
              "organisationId.keyword" => [
                "value" => "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ]
```

Comment: Do you know what? I never thought of decoding the working JSON to see how it's structured! I'll give that a try now and will reply accordingly :)